# Is there some way to make Twig stop sanitizing HTML URL links?

Tags: twig, sanitization, html-sanitizing, twig-filter

Twig does a great job of sanitizing dangerous user input. However, I'm building a particular web app where I want to allow users to post clickable URL links in public comments. Is there some way I can make Twig *not* sanitize URL links, but still sanitize everything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`raw` filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html) to prevent HTML from being escaped:

```
{{ some_html|raw }}
```

Or maybe a better option would be to use it with the [`striptags` filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/striptags.html) and whitelist `<a>` tags:

```
{{ some_html|striptags('<a>')|raw }}
```

Internally, Twig uses the [PHP `strip_tags` function](https://secure.php.net/strip_tags). Note that its documentation has this warning:

> #### Warning
>
> This function does not modify any attributes on the tags that you allow using `allowable_tags`, including the *style* and *onmouseover* attributes that a mischievous user may abuse when posting text that will be shown to other users.

[See TwigFiddle.](https://twigfiddle.com/q0wgj4)